# Duda sobre APIs y versiones de Android : minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-studio

Actualmente desarrollo mis pequeñas aplicaciones siempre en "minSdkVersion 17".

Si utilizo funciones implementadas en API 26 por ejemplo, quedarían fuera de mi aplicación los teléfonos con el sistema operativo más anticuado?

Concretamente lo digo porque he estado viendo que la forma de lanzar notificaciones cambió hace relativamente poco, y ahora se hace a través de canales y se requiere usar la API 26, por lo que si quiero mantener mi dispositivo disponible para todo el mundo y mostrar notificaciones me es imposible?

Gracias,

Edit: build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.exemple.notifprueba"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

La pregunta es, si yo aumento el minSdkVersion, dejará de estar disponible mi aplicación para muchos dispositivos móviles?

Comment: Gracias por agregar el build.gradle @MaciaEstela de hecho sdk en realidad es la famosa API, agregué una respuesta a tu pregunta (o preguntas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al definir en tu `build.gradle`  el [minSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#min)

```
minSdkVersion 17
```

**se refiere a la API mínima en la cual funcionaría tu aplicación, esto quiere decir que al publicarla en la Google Play Store  esta solo será disponible para [dispositivos con Android 4.2 o superior](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2)**

> La pregunta es, si yo aumento el minSdkVersion, dejará de estar
>   disponible mi aplicación para muchos dispositivos móviles?

Quien determina para que dispositivos con cierto sistema operativo minimo estaría disponible tu aplicación es  [minSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#min)

---

> Si utilizo funciones implementadas en API 26 por ejemplo, quedarían
>   fuera de mi aplicación los teléfonos con el sistema operativo más
>   anticuado?

De acuerdo a tu configuración únicamente no estaría disponible para los dispositivos con sistema operativo android menor a 4.2, ya que tienes definido

```
minSdkVersion 17
```

---

> Concretamente lo digo porque he estado viendo que la forma de lanzar
>   notificaciones cambió hace relativamente poco, y ahora se hace a
>   través de canales y se requiere usar la API 26, por lo que si quiero
>   mantener mi dispositivo disponible para todo el mundo y mostrar
>   notificaciones me es imposible?

**En cuanto a las notificaciones es interesante tu pregunta, te comento que la clave aquí es con que `targetSdkVersion` compiles tu aplicación.**

> - Si compilas con `targetSdkVersion 26` , [necesitas configurar `channels` para poder recibir notificaciones](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels).
> - Si compilas con `targetSdkVersion 25 o menor` , NO es necesario configurar `channels` para poder recibir notificaciones.

Incluso puedes definir `targetSdkVersion 25 o menor` y `compileSdkVersion 26` y no es necesario configurar `channels`, lo importante aquí es el `targetSdkVersion`.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    ...
    ...
}
```

Pero como recomendación siempre es mejor tomar en cuenta que debemos actualizar las aplicaciones, en algún momento debes cambiar a mínimo `targetSdk 26`, de hecho el mismo Android Studio en algún momento en el futuro ya no te permitirá usar `targetSdk 25 o menor` porque las libraries seguramente ya no lo soportarían.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración.