# Error : minSDK(API27) > deviceSDK(API23)

Tags: android, android-studio, api

Hola estoy usando la versión 3 de Android Studio, tuve muchos problemas pero pude hacer que un programa funcionara, ahora estoy creando otro, pero me sale este error:
minSDK(API27) > deviceSDK(API23) lo raro es que cambié varias veces los valores, pero nada me funciona.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jhon.pasardatosentreactivities"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error:

> minSdk(API 27) > device Sdk(API 23)

**indica que tu dispositivo ya sea emulador o físico tiene sistema operativo Android 6.0 (API 23) y en la definición de tu proyecto estas definiendo como minima version la API 27**, por lo tanto no se podrá instalar la aplicación.

```
 minSdkVersion 27
```

puedes cambiar este valor a :

```
minSdkVersion 23
```

para que pueda funcionar en tu dispositivo la aplicación.

---

Para mas información relacionada a `minSdkVersion` , revisa esta respuesta

[Duda sobre APIs y versiones de Android : minSdkVersion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174590/duda-sobre-apis-y-versiones-de-android-minsdkversion)