# Como cambiar el nivel de API en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Al momento de subir mi app a Google Play, me pide cambiar el nivel de API, busque pero me dice que tengo que ir a project structure y debería encontrar una sección donde encuentre app y ir a la sección de flavors pero sin éxito.

Comment: Cambiar el Nivel de API usada en tu aplicación debes realizarlo desde build.gradle si tienes duda en cuanto a los valores a definir, revisa : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174590/duda-sobre-apis-y-versiones-de-android-minsdkversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al no encontrar respuesta estuve revisando y resulta que si debemos ir al `project structure/modules/app`, y donde dice `compile sdk` version cambiar el nivel, y según la documentación de Android Studio https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.html
se debe escoger Android 9.0 (nivel de API 28)

y establecer esto en el manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23"
  android:targetSdkVersion="28"
  android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

[image: ayuda nivel api]

Answer (score 7):

[Anteriormente se realizaba desde el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html?hl=es-419)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"
          android:targetSdkVersion="28"
          android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

ahora **se debe realizar preferentemente dentro del archivo /app/build.gradle** , incluso estos valores sobreescriben los definidos en `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android {

    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    ...
}
```

Si deseas realizarlo desde "Project Structure" ahí solo puedes modificar los valores de `compileSdkVersion` y `buildToolsVersion` definidos en tu proyecto.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

}
```

desde el ménu, ve a `File` > `Project Structure` , selecciona tu app y selecciona `Modules`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Escoge el nivel de API que necesitas

[**Nivel de API**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html?hl=es-419#ApiLevels)