# Error al instalar una App en una tablet

Tags: android

Buennos dias.

He terminado una app y la he instalado en dos moviles y no ha dado problema, con version Android 9.

Pero mi problema es cuando lo he intantado en una tablet con una version de android 8.1.0 y me dice : "Se he produccido un error en el paquete"

Lo he compidado en Build --> Build Blundle (APKs) --> Build (APKs)

Esta es la Api comn la que lo he compidado.

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.valhondo.delgado.f7vmadmin"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que estas definiendo como minimo SDK soportado por tu aplicación el 28 ( `minSdkVersion 28`) , esto indica que la mínimo versión del [sistema operativo](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms) sería:

> Android 9 (API nivel 28)

por lo tanto tus dispositivos con sistema operativo 8 o menor no serían soportados.

Si deseas que tu dispositivo con versión 8.1.0 pueda funcionar con la aplicación considera modificar el valor de `minSdkVersion`, en este caso definir como minimo SDK :

```
minSdkVersion 27
```

Revisa esta pregunta:

[Duda sobre APIs y versiones de Android : minSdkVersion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174590/duda-sobre-apis-y-versiones-de-android-minsdkversion)